# I have encountered an error while doing sudo apt upgrade: "error processing package nullboot (--configure)"

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, software-installation, dpkg

This is the output of `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for l0oois: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm13 libllvm13:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up nullboot (0.3.0-0ubuntu1) ...
2022/07/13 19:49:31 cannot add new assets from /usr/lib/linux/efi : open /usr/lib/linux/efi: no such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package nullboot (--configure):
 installed nullboot package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nullboot
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> `open /usr/lib/linux/efi: no such file or directory`

Try creating the /usr/lib/linux/efi directory (`sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/linux/efi`).

Comment: i tried and now it shows this message : 2022/07/15 22:40:06 cannot trust boot assets used for current boot: open /sys/ke
rnel/security/tpm0/binary_bios_measurements: no such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package nullboot (--configure):
 installed nullboot package post-installation script subprocess returned error e
xit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nullboot
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)